# Can Azure Performance Tests be used to DDoS?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, performance-testing

I'm playing around with Azure Load Test for my own app and I just realized that I can type any URL into the "Test Target" field.  Does this mean that any Azure subscriber could "simulate" 1,000,000 concurrent users against my website, effectively DDoSing me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just hit upon the license and ethical problem of performance testing tools. They are a necessarily violent and destructive class of tools: the tactical nuclear weapon of tests designed to find and exploit the weak parts of your architecture.

If you read the license agreements of almost every tool there is typically a clause about using the tools only against sites you own, manage, control or where you have explicit permission from that do hold those attributes.   Also, most sites have user agreements which prohibit the use of automation against their sites outside of a defined supported API and also prohibitions against performance testing without coordination.

Does anything stop you from driving around the web neighborhood and tossing nuclear grenades at websites?  No, not really.  You have your license and user agreement constraints, assuming you choose to honor them - many don't.  You have the threat of prosecution for engaging in a DDoS attack against a site - this is usually the greater curb against behavior.

Likewise, because of their destructive power these tools should not be placed in the hands of people without training and supervision for a period of time lest they start asking, "Hmmmmm, I wonder what happens when I use 10,000,000 fake email addresses for account signups in test....only to find that they have now destroyed the ability to transfer mail in and out of the enterprise because the SMTP relay has 10,000,000 confirmation emails queued up and waiting to timeout after 72 hours as undeliverable.